# Best mysql data type to store RSA keys?

Tags: mysql, types, persistence, rsa

I have a client/server application with its users and all... The server serialization is done using SqlAlchemy over MySQL.

I am planning to assign an RSA private key to my `User` class for... certain <strike>paranoid</strike> extended security purposes. I need to store the key somewhere, and I'm thinking about storing it in an extra column of the User table.

So, if you guys think that storing an RSA private key in a MySQL table is an "acceptable" idea, what would be the best column type to use? `STRING`? a `BINARY`?

Any hint will be appreciated, including answers of the kind "*are you nuts?? storing a private key in MySQL is the worse thing you can do security-wise*". I'm pretty new to MySQL and even newer to asymmetric encryption, so I might be trying to do something very, very bad.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are going to made it an extra column in a user table make sure you only hit that table via stored procedures.  Make sure you only hit that database with stored procedures and do a general security review on the database.  A secured database is not a bad place to store keys.  I would rather that then stored on the user's PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you gotta store, you gotta store...

As to what type is best, see for yourself. Binary takes less space, but string might be more comfortable to work with. Try both options and see.

Comment: I think I'll start with Strings... I'm a voyeur... I like to see the things I store. Thanks!